# How can I convert my asp files along with the database file to an executable file i.e (.exe)

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, exe

How can I convert my asp files i.e made using Classic ASP (Vbscript) along with the database file to an executable file i.e (.exe)

Comment: Are you asking, how do you create an installer for your asp application? This is a poor question so far and is in danger of being closed or worse, downvoted.

Comment: The software that you need was called "ASPtoEXE" which I have been using for years. But the developer has since disappeared and I can no longer activate the software due to a call to home licensing check. I see it listed on software sites but it must be an old listing. It was ideal for running Classic ASP in an executable that created a mini web server running at localhost. The maker was ASP Developer Tech. If anyone knows how to contact them please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more explanation would be wise, for HTML there are products (eg HTML2Exe), they produce offline copies of a site, to PDF is also possible. But from asp ? Asp is interactive so you would need a program to do the work of the IIS server. I program also in Ruby and there it is no problem, the only thing you need is Ruby itself, a few easy to get libraries and you'r set, even with the possibility to make it into a JAR, WAR or EXE..
Try with a service like http://pdfmyurl.com/ if PDF is sufficient.
The following premeses what you ask but without databases, haven't used it

```
http://www.bestshareware.net/download/asp-to-exe.htm
```

If you mean an executable to set up your web project for clients you can do that in Visual Studio .NET, you can create a Setup or Web Setup Project and create a exe for a web application. Also with VS and ASP.net you can compile your web-project to a .dll

Comment: http://www.bestshareware.net/download/asp-to-exe.htm points to the software that I mentioned above. Discontinued and cannot be licensed. I would love to contact the author.